# Collections Set form binding wont work in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-form

Can't we use Set (HashSet, LinkedHashSet) in spring mvc form to model binding ? I have searched through web but couldn't get answer except everyone says, change Set to Map or List. Is this the way spring mvc still works wrt form to model binding? I'm not convinced with changing Set to List or Map since i respect the purpose of it, is there any workaround or resolving mechanism to keep the Set as it is and spring mvc form to model binding works.

Comment: You can only bind to indexed collections a `Set` isn't indexed hence cannot be used for binding. Only `List`s, `Map`s and arrays are indexed.

Comment: Thanks Deinum, I understood and this is the same answer i got everywhere. Does this means that Set is useless in spring mvc ? Just like List, Set is another type where we can add objects may not be using index. Can you please clarify spring mvc has support or not ? If not how can i write my own form to model binder ?

Comment: What wasn't clear about my comment, you cannot bind to a `Set` with Spring MVC. The only option is to use an indexed collection.

Comment: Ok, is there anyway we can extend the existing spring form to model binding ? Custom DataBinder will work ?

Comment: I doubt it you would have to replace the whole binding and properties resolution. But how would you bind to a Set, how would you make sure you are binding to the correct element? There is no easy way to distringuish which element, unless you are recreating the full `Set` each time, which is problematic if you have persisted sets or a incoming request not containing all elements.

Comment: I don't have the requirement to modify the existing Set element but only to add element.